# redirecting/displaying a dynamically updating file on the server to a html

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I'm working on an application in which the client needs to monitor a dynamically updated file in the server side though webpages.

Can you provide some ideas on how this is usually implemented ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll have to describe what you're trying to accomplish a little bit more to expect an accurate answer.

Comment: hey james, thanks for the quick feedback, I have a webserver which runs the script when the client requests it do so, and the server side script will update a log file as the script runs, I would also like to show this file "realtime" to the user at client browser.

Comment: Depending on the format of the log, it could be fairly easy to do so. "realtime" can either mean, interval updates or a constant connection with a framework like socket.io. Being a js fanboy, you could use js or jquery to parse the text into the webpage and then .empty() and refill the page every 30 seconds or so using setInterval();